# VBA nested looping with do until loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need a looping structure that checks a range of cells, then if the cell and a cell that is in the range equal each other then the font should turn red. My problem is that my do until loop won't get entered. This is what I have right now.
`

```
Dim finalrow As Long
finalrow = Worksheets("Redundancy").Cells(Worksheets("Redundancy").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim z As Long
Dim w As Long
Dim r As Long
w = 2
r = 0
For z = 2 To finalrow
     If Range("L" & z) = Range("L" & z + 1) & Range("J" & z) <> Range("J" & z + 1) Then
        Do Until Range("L" & z) = Range("L" & z + 1) & Range("J" & z) <> Range("J" & z + 1)
                If Cells(w, 4) = Cells(z + 1, 4 + r) Then
                    Cells(w, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    Cells(z + 1, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    If r = 4 Then
                        w = w + 1
                    End If
                End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    End If
 Next z
```

`
I changed it to this, but it exits the loop all together right when it is about to enter the do while loop.

`

```
For z = 2 To finalrow
        Do While (Range("L" & z) = Range("L" & z + 1) And Range("J" & z) <> Range("J" & z + 1))
                If Cells(w, 4) = Cells(z + 1, 4 + r) Then
                    Cells(w, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    Cells(z + 1, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    If r = 4 Then
                        w = w + 1
                    End If
                End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop
 Next z
```

`

Comment: Replace the `&` in the `If` with `And`

Comment: The `&` is a string concatenation operator. You want `And`.

Comment: I don't think you can ever enter your loop. That condition(s) and the If above it seem identical.

Comment: They are identical because they it checks the same condition. @Jeeped

Comment: Right. If *something* then do until *something*. You will never go into the Do loop. Perhaps you meant Do **WHILE**.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot just use a conditional formatting rule? Seems simple enough. btw if you want to hide hte text, don't make it the same color as the fill, change the number format to `;;;`.

Comment: @AdamCholak Jeeped is right. You're saying go into your loop if something is true, then you quickly say do it until (that previous thing is true), which it already is.

Comment: My loop still doesn't want to cooperate. Let me know how I can fix it @Jeeped

Comment: `Do Until Range("L" & z) <> Range("L" & z + 1) OR Range("J" & z) = Range("J" & z + 1)`

Comment: It needs to meet both conditions not just one, also that didn't work either @Jeeped

Comment: Are you trying to find the duplicate values between two ranges?

Comment: Where do you initialize `r` before entering the `While` loop?

Comment: There are so many WTFs in this code, that it is hurting my head. I think you would be better served to explain in detail (or with an example) what the intent is, and then someone can reply the cleanest way to do what you want. Your code is BLR (Beyond Local Repair).

Answer (score 1):

If you do this;

`Range("L" & z) = Range("L" & z + 1) and Range("J" & z) <> Range("J" & z + 1)`

you are comparing Range objects. What you instead want to do is to compare the values in those range objects. So use this instead;

`Range("L" & z).value = Range("L" & z + 1).value and Range("J" & z).value <> Range("J" & z + 1).value`

However when you use the `cells(row,column)` you don't have this problem.

I am curious though, was it not possible to use `conditional formatting` instead?

Comment: `Value` is the default member of `Range`, so in this instance there's actually no *need* to specify `.Value` (though I prefer it for readability).

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'and' operator instead of '&'.

Comment: This still doesn't fix his problem as his logic isn't correct